# CSS Nav buttons move bottom left

Tags: css

The nav buttons sit on top of the image title div. Both drop down on hover. When going to the next image, the nav buttons are at the correct location, but when you click on the previous, the whole nav screen shifts to the bottom right!

```
  nav {
         position: absolute;
  width: 100%
  height: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  z-index: 1;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -20px;
  transition: margin-top 200ms ease-in;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.4;
  right: 1px;

}
.title {
  position: absolute;
  width: 85%;
  height: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  transition: margin-top 200ms ease-in;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.title-text {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.slides:hover .title {
   margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Here is [link](https://jsfiddle.net/pa4qttwa/1/) to a fiddle.

Comment: you have a lot of mistakes there.. missing semicolons, attributes excluding themselves..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this part but code itself is clumsy

anyway still here is example : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eszhnshL/)

first of all you forgot ";" in `.nav {` between `height` and `width`
secondly dont use `position: absolute` and `float` it exclude each other
try to connect similiar `classes` like your buttons

```
.btn-prev,
.btn-next{
  color: black;
  background:white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Quick explain, I set `text-align` on `.nav` element so buttons would be set on right side inside `.nav` and `.btn-*` for `display: inline-block;` (default 
`display: block;` so it would behave similiar like text.